# Getting extra blank spaces while printing table

Tags: php, jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to print a table using Datatable Jquery , and it is giving me some extra spaces unnecessary.

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
<tr  class="data-item show">
<td class="one wide tdalign collapsing">
<div id="divwhlprodmttrcheck" class="ui checkbox">
<input id="cbwhlprodmttrcheck" type="checkbox" name="inventory[]" value="<?php echo $product->productId ?>">
<label style="padding-left:0;"></label>
 </div>
 </td>
 <td id="tdwhlprodmtin<?php echo $product->productId ?>" ><?php echo $product->ProductName ?></td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinsku<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->SKU ?></td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtincat<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->Category ?></td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinsc<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->Subcategory ?></td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinbr<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->BrandName ?>
@if($product->BrandDeleted == 1)
<i class="warning red circle icon brand" data-content="Brand has been deleted" data-variation="inverted"></i>
 @endif
</td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinsp<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->SupplierName ?>
@if($product->SuppDeleted == 1)
<i class="warning red circle icon supp" data-content="Supplier has been deleted" data-variation="inverted"></i>
@endif
</td>
 <td id="tdwhlprodmtinst<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->AvailableStock ?></td>
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinpr<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->Price ?></td>
 @if($product->Discount  == 0)
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinpr<?php echo $product->productId ?>">NA</td>
 @else
<td id="tdwhlprodmtinpr<?php echo $product->productId ?>"><?php echo $product->Discount ?>%</td>
 @endif
 <input type="hidden" id="inhidsuppmain{{$product->productId}}" value="{{$product->SupplierName}}" >
 <input type="hidden" id="inhidbrndmain{{$product->productId}}" value="{{$product->BrandName}}">
 <input type="hidden" id="tdwhlprodmtprice<?php echo $product->productId?>" value="<?php echo $product->Price ?>" name="price">
<input type="hidden" id="inhiddiscountmain{{$product->productId}}" value="{{$product->Discount}}" >
<input type="hidden" id="inhidIsOnSalemain{{$product->productId}}" value="{{$product->onsale}}" >
<input type="hidden" id="inhidIsOnClearancemain{{$product->productId}}" value="{{$product->onclearance}}" >
 <input type="hidden" name="inID" class="inid<?php echo $product->productId ?>" id="tdwhlprodmtinid<?php echo $product->productId ?>" value="<?php echo $product->productId; ?>">
<td class="tdalign collapsing"><i class="link black write icon" data-content="edit" data-variation="inverted" name="<?php echo $product->productId ?>" id="tdwhlprodmt<?php echo $product->productId; ?>" onclick="produps(4); getinValues('<?php echo $product->productId ?>'); gettingMulid('<?php echo $product->productId ?>')"></i>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I remove the code between `<tbody>` there is no spaces while code inside gives me spaces as below

[image]

I have even tried balancing it with margin-bottom , but no result yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should show you css  .. related code too ..  and .. table and thead

Comment: Can you give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) preverably as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?